# Разделение колонки CSV

Tags: python, csv

Есть CSV файл типа:

```
AAA, DDD, EEE, last_column
а,  "b,c", e,  last
```

Нужно привести его к виду

```
AAA, EEE, last_column, b, c
a,   e,   last,        b, c
```

Разделитель запятая. Нет даже идей как это можно сделать скриптом.

Comment: Отсортировать ?

Comment: А запятая в значении (не как разделитель) всегда будет без пробелов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть test.csv:

```
AAA, DDD, EEE, last_column
а,  "b,c", e,  last
f,  "r,p", m,  foo
```

То можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)
res = df["DDD"].str.split(",", n=1, expand = True)

for x in res:
    df[x] = res[x]

df.drop(columns =["DDD"], inplace = True)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Что даст нам `result.csv`:

```
AAA,EEE,last_column,0,1
а,e,last,b,c
f,m,foo,r,p
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что было нужно.